# What's the non brute force way to filter a Python dictionary?

Tags: python

I can filter the following dictionary like:

```
data = {
    1: {'name': 'stackoverflow', 'traffic': 'high'},
    2: {'name': 'serverfault', 'traffic': 'low'},
    3: {'name': 'superuser', 'traffic': 'low'},
    4: {'name': 'mathoverflow', 'traffic': 'low'},
}

traffic = 'low'

for k, v in data.items():
    if v['traffic'] == traffic:
        print k, v
```

Is there an alternate way to do the above filtering?

Comment: Unless you keep things sorted in a certain way, the best algorithm you will have is O(n) in time, which is pretty mcuh what you're doing.

Comment: if this costs too much performance, you have to turn the data structure around, i.e. for fast lookup build lists of sites with foo traffic at the same time you build the dictionary.

Comment: To follow up @hop, if you need to do this sort of lookup "a lot" on an "unchanging" dataset, key the items off of the value you're searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some level the filter will have to do exactly what you describe.  If you're going to filter on the values, you'll have to process each one, one-by-one.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this a lot, you could have two dictionaries, one for each direction.  The new dictionary will map values to lists of values.  This is a good idea if you will be doing this reverse lookup more than once.

Answer (score 1):

In principle — no.  You could rewrite the code slightly, but it would still do the same — iterating through all the values.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but they're all brute-force.

```
dict((k, v) for (k, v) in data.iteritems() if v['traffic'] == traffic)
```